# Handle form submission in angularJS component

Tags: angularjs

I have a component (see below) which when routed to using /vehicleSearch, retrieves some data (via a service 'Vehicle') to populate drop down boxes on the template vehicle-search-template.html.

```
angular.
  module('vehicleSearch').
  component('vehicleSearch', {
    templateUrl: 'vehicle-search/vehicle-search.template.html',
    controller: ['Vehicle',
      function VehicleSearchController(Vehicle) {
        this.makes = Vehicle.resource2.query();
      }
    ]
  });
```

The template is a form with an input box and then a submit button.

```
<div>
<h4>Vehicle Search</h4>
<form ng-submit="searchVehicles()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>VRM: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vrm" ng-model="vehicleSearchForm.vrm" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Make: </td>
            <td>
                <select ng-options="make.desc for make in $ctrl.makes" ng-model="vehicleSearchForm.make">
                    <option value="" label="Please select a vehicle make.."/>       
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Model: </td>
            <td>
                <select ng-options="model.desc for model in $ctrl.models" ng-model="vehicleSearchForm.model">
                    <option value="" label="Please select a vehicle model.."/>      
                </select>   
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="search"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

When I submit this form, can I then handle this submission in the same component and redirect to another URL which will be routed to another component? How do I create another method in the controller?

Comment: isn't it just `this.searchVehicles = function(){...}`?

Comment: hi thanks for swift response. I added following code inside the VehicleSearchController function this.searchVehicles = function(){alert('submit');}; but still not getting alert.

Comment: try $scope.searchVehicles = function(){...} after injecting the scope in the controller as u did with vehicles

Comment: @user2554194 did you call it with `ng-submit="$ctrl.searchVehicles()"` ?

Comment: Yes that was it Aleksey. Many thanks. Apologies for noob question.